# How can I rotate and scale the collision cylinder, that it will fit perfectly on the wheel?

Tags: collision

[image: Cylinder collision]

The cylinder collision should fit perfectly on wheel at x axis.

Cylinder is supposed to be rotated and scaled, that it would fit to the edges of the wheel.

Some people recommend me using Delta transform, but I don't know how to use it.

Comment: If i will rotate it and scale it, it will also effect to its host object which is that wheel

Comment: If this is for Rigid Body, the collision-surface can be set to Convex Hull.. or.. would some other generation of Convex Hull suffice?

Comment: If you really want to use rigid body to control the tank, you should 1) align all objects along the main axis 2) use cylinders/balls (primitive) objects as collision objects - don't use convex hulls if not needed - it slows the simulations down 3) if your collision cylinder (shape) is not on the rotation axis use the delta rotation to rotate them "right" you should need only one axis to fix this, If you need more, apply rotation to your mesh object before. After doing this, Blender automatically fits the cylinder shape perfectly for you